# at command strange behaviour

Tags: linux, cron, at-job

This is the first time i am playing with the at command in linux and notice something strange. Say i create this test file:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
echo "count is $count"
```

then i issue

```
at -f /full/path/to/myscript.sh -v 13:00 -m
```

and wait for it to run. Then in my mail, the value of count variable is nothing. What could be wrong?

```
To: root@localhost.localdomain
Status: R

count is

&
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your commands are being run by bash, and not some other interpreter like csh?  I don't think the shebang line has any effect in an at job -- the commands are simply piped into whichever shell is specified via the SHELL environment variable.

Comment: yes, it should be bash. I am running it as root and my shell is bash.

Comment: at jobs are run with /bin/sh (which still doesn't explain the issue though).